# How do I carry over data into another file PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php file that does the below.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `players` WHERE  `Banned` = 1");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
$username = $row['Username'];
$lastip = $row['LastIP'];
$level = $row['Level'];

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>$username</td>";
if ($lastip > 1){
    echo "<td>$lastip</td>";
} else {
    echo '<td>No IP found!</td>';
}
echo "<td>$level</td>";
echo "<td>Country</td>";
echo "<td><a href='unban.php'>Unban</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

I want to make unban,php unban the users IP address but i'm not sure how to carry the data over to unban.php

Comment: Exactly which data do you want to "send"/"carry over" to the next file unban.php

Answer (score 2):

You can do a:

```
echo "<td><a href='unban.php?ip=" . $lastip . "'>Unban</a></td>";
```

And in the file unban.php you use `$_GET['ip']` to get the QueryString Value with the key ip, which is passed in the URL.

If you have an ID in the database, use that to pass it to unban.php.

There are 2 request types to pass data to another page, $_GET and $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

You can easy use:

```
include("filename") into your unban.php
```

or using sessions:

```
$_SESSION["name"]=data;
```

or using forms or directly by url( but if is important info don't required to use it)

Answer (score 0):

pass a username in get parameter in url so you can identify the user, ex:
href='unban.php?username={$username}'

Answer (score 0):

Possible to your code:

```
echo "<td><a href='unban.php?ip=" . $lastip . "&username=" . $username . "'>Unban</a></td>";
```

script and query unban would like this:

```
$lastip = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ip']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `players` SET  `banned` = '0' where LastIP='$lastip' and username='$username'") or die(mysql_error());
```